# How can I use DynamoDB Rest API using query parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Having read and followed all the instructions on [Signing AWS Requests with Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html), I have managed to create my JavaScript API which connects to DynamoDB using the REST API.

It works fine when the browser allows setting custom headers, but what about older browsers (such as IE 6) that do not support this feature?

I have successfully encoded all my authentication information in the request's url but I seem to be missing a substitute for the `X-Amz-Target` header.

Here is a sample URL:

```
https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
?X-Amz-Target=DynamoDB_20120810.Scan
&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Credential=xxxxxxxxx%2F20151216%2Fus-east-1%2Fdynamodb%2Faws4_request
&X-Amz-Date=20151216T182124Z
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-date
&X-Amz-Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As you can see I have added the query parameter `X-Amz-Target` hoping it would replace the `X-Amz-Target` header, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException"
}
```

Which indicates that `X-Amz-Target` is clearly not being read.

Now, this does not guarantee that I'm even sending my authentication information correctly, as AWS always complains about authorization only when everything else is fine. (The same algorithm works when using headers though, so I can't think why it would fail)

Getting to the point, my question is: **How can I use DynamoDB Rest API via query parameters and not via custom headers?**

Comment: You were correct about my first answer. I did 'read' it at one point since I have this working for my application, but forgot about that bit! I removed the answer since it was obviously wrong. Are you URI encoding the values for your canonical request as described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html ?

Comment: @craigts Yup, I'm using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Ok, Then the only other thing I can think of is that you need to add the other x-amz-* headers to your signed headers. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html Says that it is required, but some other examples don't show that.